# Last Element of XML file.. How?

Tags: xml

am using Asp.net 2.0 and not using linq. Is it possible to get  an attribute of the last element  in an XML file. I want to get the  last elements attribute "articleId" value (4). Now the last number value will change with each new article  added to the Xml file. What's the best way to read through an XML file find the last "content" entry and get its article attribute value.

```
<blog>

<content articleId="1" category=""  img="" month="" title="" user=""
 date="" Description="" >
</content>g>

<content articleId="2" category=""  img="" month="" title="" user=""
 date="" Description="" >
</content>

<content articleId="3" category=""  img="" month="" title="" user=""
 date="" Description="" >
</content>

<content articleId="4" category=""  img="" month="" title="" user=""
 date="" Description="" >
</content>

</blog>
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to place my xml

Comment: +1 for providing full detail of problem in a proper way.=)

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();        
xmldoc.Load("Your_XML_FILE.xml");
xmldoc.DocumentElement.LastChild.Attributes.Item(0).Value
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [XPath](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2009031001&page=1), then grab the value of the `articleId` attribute from the returned node.

```
//content[last()]
```